# How to stop scoped service using Cancellation Token?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am looking for a way to stop the `Scoped background service` using a `Cancellation Token`. I followed the following steps:

## ScopedAlertingService.cs

```
namespace BackgroundTasksSample.Services
{
    internal interface IScopedAlertingService
    {
        Task DoWork(System.Threading.CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }
    public class ScopedAlertingService : IScopedAlertingService
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ScopedAlertingService(ILogger<ScopedAlertingService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task DoWork(System.Threading.CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                executionCount++;
                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "Alert: Scoped Processing Service is working. Count: {Count}", executionCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## ConsumedServiceHostedService.cs

```
namespace BackgroundTasksSample.Services
{
    public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> _logger;

        public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services,
            ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
        {
            Services = services;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }


        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
            _stoppingCts.CancelAfter(30000);

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);

                using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedProcessingService =
                        scope.ServiceProvider
                            .GetRequiredService<IScopedAlertingService>();

                    
                    await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
                }
            }
    }

        private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedProcessingService =
                    scope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<IScopedAlertingService>();

                await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is stopping.");

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
    }
```

I am running this service using `IServiceCollection`

```
#region snippet2
services.AddHostedService<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
services.AddScoped<IScopedAlertingService, ScopedAlertingService>();
#endregion
```

I am using the following code to stop the service after 30 seconds:

```
 CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
 _stoppingCts.CancelAfter(30000);
```

But the debugger is not going to `stopAsync` method of `ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService`. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: How have you proved is not stopped? I mean your logs are going to have million of events in them `executionCount++;  _logger.LogInformation("` you are just trashing a cpu core in loop as fast you can. I think you need to rethink your test

Comment: The purpose of [linked token sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=net-5.0) is the opposite of what you are doing.  Linked CTS is designed to *listen* to cancellation in the linked token, not to propagade cancellation.

Comment: @00110001 Because I put the debugger and also tried to add in `console.writeline`. Test cases are working fine. I was looking for a way to stop the service after 30 seconds and I can see the counter is going beyond 100 seconds.

So, When I checked out my console. It was not there. (Adding the console.writeline in above code as well)

Comment: @Nick Ah! Could you provide me a hint on how should I stop the service or how to pass the stopped token here?

Comment: You are creating a linked token source and not using its token? In essence you are just ignoring it

Comment: @00110001 Could you please refer to a link on how to not ignore the link or how to use it? I tried and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject `IHostedService` as `Singleton` then you can call stop method on back ground service.

**Updated:**
In hosted service the stopasync only called when application shutdown but in your code you can use this and it works:

```
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
            _stoppingCts.CancelAfter(30000);

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

            while (!_stoppingCts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000, _stoppingCts.Token);

                using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedProcessingService =
                        scope.ServiceProvider
                            .GetRequiredService<IScopedAlertingService>();

                    
                    await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(_stoppingCts.Token);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Saeed. Which controller is this? Do I need to create a new controller or are you talking about `ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService`

Comment: @Payal_Thakur Controller or any where that you want pass the ``CancellationToken``, If you don't have any controller (if your project is not web application). you can do option 2.

Comment: I used the second option and updated the configure file in startup but the result is the same.

Comment: `          services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
            services.AddHostedService<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
            services.AddScoped<IScopedAlertingService, ScopedAlertingService>();`

Comment: I think it's stopping the service but the debug point is not coming to `StopAsync` method. Is this unusual?

Comment: As I said ``StopAsync`` called when application shutdown so breakpoint will not hit until application stopped.